# Extracting LiDAR metrics with TerraScan?

Tags: lidar, statistics, extract, fusion, terrascan

I want to extract from a las file statistics such as height percentiles (percentile 95, for example) among others.

I can do it with Fusion (using `Cloudmetrics` and `Gridmetrics` tools), but I would like to do it with TerraScan. Is it possible?

Comment: This is the answer that I've received from Terrasolid Suport:    Dear Josep,

there is no tool in TScan for extracting advanced statistics from laser points. If you could clarify what exactly you want to do, we can forward it as a new features request to our software developer. It's then up to him if and when he will implement the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TerraScan can't extract advanced metrics such as the ones available from Fusion's tools `Cloudmetrics` and `Gridmetrics`.

Chapters 10 and 12 in [TerraScan user's guide](http://terrasolid.com/download/user_guides.php) mention that is possible to extract just some basic metrics such as:

- count of points.
- minimum and maximum elevation per point class.

---

<sub>References in TerraScan user's guide:</sub>

<sub>Chapter 10 - Main Window Menu Commands:</sub>
<sub>"Show statistics command: displays basic statistics information about laser points. In the upper part of the Statistics window, the amount of all points, active points and neighbour points are listed, as well as the elevation range for all points. In the lower part, the separate classes are listed with the point count, minimum elevation and maximum elevation values for each class."</sub>

<sub>Chapter 12 - Working with Projects.</sub>
<sub>"Show statistics command: calculates simple statistics for the block binary files. The output dialog includes information about classes, point count as well as minimum, maximum, and median elevation values."</sub>